# JavaFx button not working on Mac

Tags: maven, javafx

So I have created an application using javaFX in Eclipse. I packaged an executable jar using Maven, with the zenjava javafx-maven-plugin version 2.0. I package in the command line using mvn clean jfx:jar. This creates a javafx/app subfolder in my target, which includes a lib folder and the executable jar.

When I run this executable jar on my Ubuntu or Windows machine, everything seems to work fine. On Mac however, I am having trouble. I have a welcome page that shows up first. It has a small description of the application and a button for users to push to continue on to the application. For some reason the button doesnt do anything on Mac. It works fine on Windows and Ubuntu. Any ideas why this is happening? Do I have to include anything extra for Mac?

Comment: Can you post the OS version and JRE version of the mac pls?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks
java version "1.7.0_51"

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue on Jira (JavaFX Bugtracker) concerning Mouse events on buttons disapearing. It was not exactly your MAC version (in the issue they named 10.8.2) but the issue has been fixed for the JavaFX 8 release (codename lombard). You might want to try the JavaFX 8 beta and see whether your bug has been fixed.

In case you'd like to see the issue: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-26395

Comment: Thanks I will look into it, the interesting thing is that we have another JavaFX application that works fine on Mac...